# How to get h.264 to work in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, video, html5, playback

I never had any problems with h.264 playback on Ubuntu 14.04 until recently. I am using Opera Developer as default browser (yep, I know) and there´s known bug for not playing h.264 videos. But other browsers worked flawlessly so if I needed to watch something, I was one click away. Yesterday I updated Ubuntu and alongside I updated Opera Developer, Google Chrome, Firefox and Vivaldi. After this update, I can´t play h.264 videos anywhere. All browsers show nothing, only weird white and black fragmented stuff. Audio works. /html5 site on YouTube shows everything is ok, but when I try online html5 support tests, h.264 is missing. I tried everything what I was able to find on forums. h264 is installed, gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg is installed from PPA, gstreamer1.0-libav is installed too. Any idea what to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar issue on 16.04 with Vivaldi.

1. Sites to check Video playback:

   - [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html)
   - [Youtube HTML5 Test Page](http://www.youtube.com/html5)
2. Install the `libffmpeg` library:

   - `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra`
   - Revisit step 1 and test.
3. For Vivaldi snapshot, but maybe similar to other browsers:

   - `cd /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs`
   - `sudo install libffmpeg.so /opt/vivaldi-snapshot/libffmpeg.so`
   - Revisit step 1 and test.
   - [Background Information](https://gist.github.com/ruario/bec42d156d30affef655)